# How would I convert an XLS to a CSV file in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, csv, xls

I've been searching for days to find a PHP script that will either read an MsExcel(myFile.xls) file  and convert it into a CSV (myFile.csv) file and output it. Does anyone know how I could do this and/or maybe a few code examples?

Comment: XLS means MS Excel, right?  On Windows one could use Office Automation (basically a glorified VB script) to do it.  Have you considered that?  Or would a LibreOffice approach be more palatable?

Answer (score 2):

This code reads the .xls file and then converts it to the .csv line by line.

But i will suggest to look for any external library or function to do the same, it will be more easy -

```
/* Get the excel.php class here: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/1919.html */
require_once("../classes/excel.php");
$inputFile=$argv[1];
$xlsFile=$argv[2];

if( empty($inputFile) || empty($xlsFile) ) {
    die("Usage: ". basename($argv[0]) . " in.csv out.xls\n" );
}

$fh = fopen( $inputFile, "r" );
if( !is_resource($fh) ) {
    die("Error opening $inputFile\n" );
}

/* Assuming that first line is column headings */
if( ($columns = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, "\t")) == false ) {
    print( "Error, couldn't get header row\n" );
    exit(-2);
}
$numColumns = count($columns);

/* Now read each of the rows, and construct a
    big Array that holds the data to be Excel-ified: */
$xlsArray = array();
$xlsArray[] = $columns;
while( ($rows = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, "\t")) != FALSE ) {
    $rowArray = array();
    for( $i=0; $i&lt;$numColumns;$i++ ) {
        $key = $columns[$i];
        $val = $rows[$i];
        $rowArray["$key"] = $val;
    }
    $xlsArray[] = $rowArray;
    unset($rowArray);
}
fclose($fh);

/* Now let the excel class work its magic. excel.php
    has registered a stream wrapper for "xlsfile:/"
    and that's what triggers its 'magic': */
$xlsFile = "xlsfile:/".$xlsFile;
$fOut = fopen( $xlsFile, "wb" );
if( !is_resource($fOut) ) {
    die( "Error opening $xlsFile\n" );
}
fwrite($fOut, serialize($xlsArray));
fclose($fOut);

exit(0);
```

Comment: By the looks of it, that script converts CSV to XLS

Comment: @Shane first download the class file - http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/1919.html

Comment: the class excel.php perform both operations CSV to XLS and XLS to CSV

Comment: @Shane go to this page - phpclasses.org/browse/package/1919.html  
here you can find some example files